# Expectation of the squared difference of two Gaussian random variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Consider two independent standard Gaussian random variables $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and their sum $Z = X +Y$. [We know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) that $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$. Now consider the problem of deriving $\mathbb{E}[(Z - aY)^2]$ for some scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

To begin, I attempted to expand as follows:
$$\mathbb{E}[(Z - aY)^2] = \mathbb{E}[Z^2] - 2a\mathbb{E}[ZY] + \mathbb{E}[Y^2].$$
The first and final terms are easily computed using the definition of variance; however, I cannot seem to be able to find out what $\mathbb{E}[ZY]$ is. Clearly $Z$ and $Y$ are not independent (right? since knowing $Y$ would shift the distribution on $Z$).

Not sure where to go from here, do I want to resort to the definition of expectation or is there something easier?

Comment: $Z-aY=X+(1-a)Y$ has a Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1+(1-a)^2,$ as you can readily calculate.

Comment: @whuber Doh! Thanks!

Comment: @whuber Aren't you jumping the gun a little in deducing that $Z$ is normal? The OP doesn't state that $X$ and $Y$ are _jointly_ normal (unless you think that the Wikipedia page that the OP links to is a sufficient indication that he has joint normality in mind).

Comment: @Dilip I considered that, but noticed that the question also stipulates that $Z$ has a Normal distribution.  I took that as the "sufficient indication" you seek.

Comment: I had independence of $X$ and $Y$ in mind, which would imply that they are jointly normal. I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the OP has confessed that $X$ and $Y$ have been *independent* $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables all along, which of course implies that $Z=X+Y \sim \mathcal N(0,2)$, consider that
$E[Z-aY] = E[Z]-aE[Y] = 0$ and so 
\begin{align}E[(Z-aY)^2 &= \operatorname{var}(Z-aY)\\
&= \operatorname{var}(X+Y-aY)\\
&= \operatorname{var}(X+(1-a)Y)\\
&= \operatorname{var}(X) + (1-a)^2\operatorname{var}(Y) &{\scriptstyle{\text{since}~X~\text{and}~aY~\text{are independent random variables}}}\\
& &{\scriptstyle{\text{and}~\operatorname{var}((1-a)Y)~ = ~(1-a)^2\operatorname{var}(Y).}}
\end{align}
And of course, $Z-aY$ is a normal random variable.

Comment: It was never necessary to assume independence: from the original statement that $Z$ has a distribution with variance $2$ you can obtain the answer, because it implies $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated and that suffices for your calculation.